# Не понимаю работу (Math.random())

Tags: java, математика

```
public class Generator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] surnameList = {"Вишневский", "Сидоров", "Заперской", "Вафлистов", "Мичурин", "Иванов", "Алеексеев", "Петухов"};
        String[] nameList = {"Александр", "Иван", "Алексей", "Максим", "Владимир", "Геннадий", "Петр", "Ярослав"};
        String[] patronymicList = {"Анатольевич", "Александрович", "Владимирович", "Алексеевич", "Сергеевич", "Максимович", "Ярославович", "Иванович"};

        // Вычисляем, сколько слов в каждом списке
        int surnameLength = surnameList.length;
        int nameLength = nameList.length;
        int patronymicLength = patronymicList.length;

        //Генерируем три случайных числа
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * surnameLength);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * nameLength);
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * patronymicLength);

        //Строим фразу
        String phrase = surnameList[rand1] + " " + nameList[rand2] + " " + patronymicList[rand3];

        //Выводим фразу
        System.out.println("Ваш напарник это - " + phrase);
    }
}
```

Не понимаю как отрабатывает `Math.random()` и что он генерирует и умножает на `surnameLength` например. В дебаге я не смог посмотреть что генерирует `Math.random()`.
В книге по этому примеру написано: 
Метод `random()` возвращает случайно число между 0 и 1 поэтому мы должны умножить это число на количество элементов (длину массива) в нашем списке. Но если у нас метод `random()` возвратит как написано `0` и `0 умножается на 8(длина каждого массива)`, то будет по итогу в этом случае всегда 0 индекс `(8*0=0).`

Comment: 1. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте заголовок так, чтобы он по возможности заканчивался на `?`. 2. Какая у вас проблема?

Comment: Хотелось бы как отрабатывает метод random(), я прочитал и не понял как он отрабатывает в данном примере

Comment: Я проверял вот так System.out.println((int) Math.random()); и каждый раз 0 выдает, получается в данном примере всегда будет 0 индекс? Если 0 * на 8 длину списка массива

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работа `Math.random()`:

Он случайным образом генерирует числа от 0 до 1, т.е. `0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ... 0.9`.

Проблема у вас в том, что `Math.random()` возвращает `double` значение меньше 1, а при использовании `(int) Math.random()` оно округляется в меньшую сторону, т.е. к 0.

Comment: то есть всегда будет 0 умножаться на 8?Как я понял так

Comment: и в итоге всегда будет 0 индекс, но как я вижу из запуска этого кода, так это то, что не только 0 индекс выдает, но и разные индекса, как это работает все равно не понтмаю

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван нет, вы сначала умножайте на 8 а потом преобразуйте в инт

Comment: Вот что мне нужно было: вы сначала умножайте на 8 а потом преобразуйте в инт, всё спасибо большое

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван пожалуйста :)